# Why does the execution of a Python script fail on running it with a batch file with the Windows Task Scheduler which uses vir env?

Tags: python-3.x, batch-file, cmd, anaconda, windows-task-scheduler

I have a *Python* script on my *Windows* machine which has to be run in a virtual environment in order to satisfy package dependencies.
I have created a batch file to use it with *Task Scheduler* which looks like the following:

```
call activate vir_env
python "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\Scripts\script.py"
call conda deactivate
pause
set /p id="Press enter when finished"
```

This batch file executes successfully when I run it by manually double clicking on it. But it is failing after a period of execution when I schedule it for execution by the *Task Scheduler*. (I am saving this batch file on my desktop and pointing the scheduler to read it from there.)

I also see the following line on cmd while running it manually.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61347/devtools/browser/d86ec8f2-7af2-4a2b-89f4-6c6f7025cc02
```

But I get the following notification if I schedule and run it with *Task Scheduler*:

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55329/devtools/browser/e8cd5010-6b41-4d35-a465-78a75e87a547
```

That can be seen in the error output as posted below.

```
DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55329/devtools/browser/e8cd5010-6b41-4d35-a465-78a75e87a547
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\Scripts\script.py", line 432, in <module>
    gv.save(deps, buffer, fmt='png')
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\lib\site-packages\holoviews\util\__init_.py", line 820, in save
    return renderer_obj.save(obj, filename, fmt=fmt, resources=resources,
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py", line 627, in save
    rendered = self_or_cls(plot, fmt)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\renderer.py", line 201 in __call__
    data = self._figure_data(plot, fmt, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\lib\site-packages\holoviews\plotting\bokeh\renderer.py", line 131, in _figure_data
    img = get_screenshot_as_png(plot.state, driver=state.webdriver)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io\export.py", line 223, in get_screenshot_as_png
    web_driver.maximize_window()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 737, in maximize_window
    self.execute(command, params)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Anaconda\envs\vir_env\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.comnon.exceptions.NoSuchWindowException: Message: Browsing context has been discarded
```

How can this be possible?

The dev tool link seems to be different in the two cases.

Could this be the potential cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but found a solution without using task scheduler

Create a file and name it eg `Example.bat`

Edit the file and paste this code

```
set Path_To_File=C:\Path\To\File

set SunDay_Time=11:34

set MonDay_Time=13:20

set TuesDay_Time=07:30

set WednesDay_Time=02:57

set ThursDay_Time=11:42

set Friday_Time=23:59

set Saturday_Time=23:59




@echo off
:loop
timeout 10
for /f %%i in ('powershell ^(get-date^).DayOfWeek') do set day=%%i
SET "HH=%TIME:~0,2%
SET "MM=%TIME:~3,2%
if %day%==Sunday set Time_Run=%SunDay_Time%
if %day%==Monday set Time_Run=%MonDay_Time%
if %day%==Tuesday set Time_Run=%TuesDay_Time%
if %day%==Wednesday set Time_Run=%WednesDay_Time%
if %day%==Thursday set Time_Run=%ThursDay_Time%
if %day%==Friday set Time_Run=%Friday_Time%
if %day%==Saturday set Time_Run=%Saturday_Time%
if "%HH%:%MM%" EQU "%Time_Run%" start "%Path_To_File%"
goto loop
```

Edit this section

Modify the path name of the program you want to run at the specified time, and modify the time you want to run the program through this section, and then save the file

```
set Path_To_File=C:\Path\To\File

set SunDay_Time=11:34

set MonDay_Time=13:20

set TuesDay_Time=07:30

set WednesDay_Time=02:57

set ThursDay_Time=11:42

set Friday_Time=23:59

set Saturday_Time=23:59
```

Press `Windows` and `R` and type `shell:startup`

Create a file and name it `example.vbs`

Edit the file and paste this code

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Path\To\File.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

Replace `C:\Path\To\File.bat` with the path of the batch file and save the file